# VBScript get temp folder

Tags: vbscript, temp

`fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)` correctly returns the temp folder for me, when run from a VBS file. However, when run from within an Autodesk Revit journal file, which has historically been VBS compliant, I get back the proper path and a GUID after Temp. I had never seen this before, and I am unsure if this is perhaps a known issue in newer builds of Windows 10 (it's been about three years since I tested this), or is this more likely an issue with Autodesk's implementation of VBScript support? I suspect the latter.
Which then raises the question, is there another good way to get the full temp path in VBScript?
I could use

```
Dim strUser : strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
"C:\Users\" & strUser & "\AppData\Local\Temp"
```

It's just been so long since I played with VBS, I'm not remembering if there is a better answer, or this is the consistently workable way to go. And, more than anything I want to know if `.GetSpecialFolder(2)` is broken in some way in Windows, or just by Autodesk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it logical to have different values on different environments  / scripting hosts?

`GetSpecialFolder(2)` simply returns the process environment variable named `TMP`. Any change on that variable *-which is quite legal-*, affects the value that `GetSpecialFolder(2)` returns.

> [GetSpecialFolder method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getspecialfolder-method#settings)
>
> Constant: TemporaryFolder
> Value: 2
> The Temp folder is used to store temporary files. Its path is found in the `TMP` environment variable.

Since `GetSpecialFolder(2)` will always return an existing directory path I probably would use it with the thought that this is intended by the environment; the `Autodesk Revit`.

Other than that, I'd use something like below if I want the usual temporary path because even they are rare, there are installations where system drive is not `C:`. Relying on `%localappdata%` makes more sense in that manner.

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
TempPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%localappdata%\Temp")
```